# How to shut down openconnect cleanly?

Tags: terminal, vpn, openconnect

I tried using openconnect today for the first time to connect to my organization's VPN. However, once connected, it runs in the foreground of the terminal and the only way I could see to close the connection was to use `CTRL-C`. Is this an acceptable way to close the openconnect session cleanly? If not, what is the preferred method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `Ctrl-C` (i.e. SIGINT) cleanly shuts it down, according to https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/manual.html#heading5.

Personally I run openconnect in a terminal and use `Ctrl-C` to shut it down; some people might prefer to use NetworkManager, systemd-networkd, etc. to manage openconnect connections.

Answer (score 2):

**To kill [`openconnect`](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/) or [`openconnect-sso`](https://github.com/vlaci/openconnect-sso)** ("OpenConnect Single Sign-On (SSO)": a wrapper which allows SAML 2-factor authentication via Okta, in place of the Cisco AnyConnect client) **from another terminal**, you can send it the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> `SIGINT` interrupt signal safely like this:

```bash
# to cleanly kill openconnect or openconnect-sso
sudo pkill --signal SIGINT openconnect
# or (same thing)
sudo pkill -SIGINT openconnect
```

If you use `sudo pkill openconnect` instead, it sends the default `SIGTERM` termination signal instead, which force-kills it and does *not* kill it cleanly. If you make this simple mistake, simply turn your WiFi card OFF then back ON again by toggling it with <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> or equivalent (look for the wifi beacon icon) on your laptop keyboard. This resets your internet connection so your internet will work again.